# Write a 1-dim array on a file in Julia

Tags: arrays, file, julia

I have a 1-dim array that I am trying to write on a row on a file. I tried

```
writedlm(fileName, myArray, "\t")

join(fileName, myArray)

write(fileName, myArray)
```

In all cases, it writes `myArray` on the file in a column. I would like to have in written in a row. How can I achieve this?

Comment: What about `write` and `join`?

Comment: are you sure it doesn't work with `transpose`, works for me

Comment: hum... well indeed it works! I probably made a mistake somehow when I tried that at first place. Sorry for the basic question then. Do you think I should delete my question? I would rather suggest that I delete the answer that is in my question and you post an answer. This might be useful to other new Julia users. As you haven't reacted so far, I posted the answer. Feel free to post your own and I'll delete mine if you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transpose your array

```
writedlm(fileName, transpose(myArray), "\t")
```